Changing list indentation only in footnotes
I'm typesetting a critical edition of a nineteenth-century manuscript which itself overuses footnotes.  The notes are often long, but are generally sufficiently important to the main text that formatting them as endnotes would be hindrance to the reader – often they correct a statement the author subsequently realised was false.  They frequently include block quotations.  I know this isn't good practice, but it's what the author did, and my job is to reproduce that.
Our house style is to format footnotes indented (as with the hang option to the footmisc package); I'd need a very good reason to deviate from that style.  Block quotes are currently set using the quote or quotation environments, though I'm not adverse to moving to the quoting environment if that helps solve this problem.
Our current style has \footnotemargin and \leftmargini set to the same amount, and visually these look about right.  However, this means that block quotes in footnotes don't indent.  (This strikes me as potentially a bug in the footmisc package.)  I can fix this in any individual footnote with \advance\leftmargini\footnotemargin, but I'd like to fix it once in my style file.
I'm sure this must be a simple enough job, probably by using one of the patch commands in the etoolbox package to add increase \leftmargini at the start of the body of the footnote, but I can't quite fine the right runes.  Can anyone help?  In case it's relevant, I'm also using the manyfoot and fnpct packages, which I imagine are doing their own patching of the footnote macros.  I'm also using xelatex.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[hang,multiple,splitrule]{footmisc}
\usepackage{manyfoot,fnpct}
\setlength\footnotemargin\leftmargini
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]%
  \footnote{This is a footnote.
    % I'd like this line to happen automatically in all footnotes:
    % \advance\leftmargini\footnotemargin
    \begin{quote}\lipsum[2][1-3]\end{quote}}
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[3][1-5]\par\lipsum[3][9-]
\end{quotation}
\lipsum[4][1-4]
\end{document}


I'm not sure to fully understand your issue: without \advance\leftmargini\footnotemargin the quotes in footnotes have an extra margin. Anyway you could define a dedicated environment, such as \NewDocumentEnvironment{footquote}{}{\begingroup\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\footnotemargin}\begin{quote}}  {\end{quote}\endgroup}.

It's only barely indented, and only because of the very small difference between the default list indent and the default footnote indent.  I've just edited the MWE to set them equal and you can then see the footnote quote is not indented at all without the explicit \advance.  I really don't want a new environment.  For one thing, it means editing thousands (literally!) of pages of manuscript.

Well, even after your edit I still see an expected margin around the quote: here what I get without the explicit \advance... (with extra text to show the margins).

Interesting.  I wonder whether we have different versions of the footmisc package and either yours is newer and this has been fixed as a bug, or mine is newer and the bug as only recently been introduced.  Mine appears to be version 6.0d (or at least, it says \ProvidesPackage{footmisc}[2022/03/08 v6.0d ...]).  What is yours?

2023/07/05 v6.0f. I use a (nearly) up to date 2024 Tex Live distribution.

Thank you.  I've just downloaded that version and it all works perfectly.  I guess this was a bug that has now been fixed.  Would you like to turn this into an answer for me to accept, or shall I?

You can write an answer. Anyway the question should be closed, as the issue is caused by an outdated package.
